# mansions of madness using a non-action equipment requires evade?

Tags: mansions-of-madness

In Mansions of Madness, the rules say that "an investigator must make an evade test before moving or performing non-attack actions."
What if the investigator uses an equipment card which does not have the word "Action" on it. Does that require an evade test ?

Answer (score 1):

You have already quoted all the relevant rules.

Does this equipment require you move?
Does this equipment require you to take a non-attack action?

If yes, make an evade test first.
If no, You don't make the evade test.

Comment: Well, the question is: the equipment which doesn't have the word "Action" in it, is it still considered an action or not ? The rules say that if the equipment doesn't have the word "Action" then it doesn't require you to spend an action point. But it doesn't say if it is still considered as an action for the purposes of evading.

Comment: The rules for the investigator turn also say that on his turn, the investigator may either move or perform an action. So it could be interpreted that everything is considered either a move or an action. So using the above mentioned equipment would qualify as an action, since it is not a move.

Comment: @CristianMocanu Can you provide an example of an ability about which you aren't sure whether it requires an action?

Comment: There are many examples, but the one I encountered in play is the "Tonic of Inspiration" artifact card from The Yellow Sign expansion story. The card reads: Artifact. You may discard this card on your turn to roll a die. 1-6: Heal 2 damage or 2 horror. 7-10: Gain 1 random Kings Court card from the supply.

Comment: This is not an action. Otherwise it would be "Action: Roll a die." et cetera. Eventually it could be "You may discard this card as an action to roll a die"

Comment: So you would conclude that it doesn't need an evade test, right ?

Comment: Yes, that's right..